# Fake proof: $FinVect_k$ is not a closed category

Tags: category-theory, fake-proofs

[nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite-dimensional+vector+space) very unequivocally states that $FinVect_k$ (finite dimensional vector spaces over the field $k$) is a closed category. However, I have a fake proof below that $FinVect_k$ is not a closed category.

> **Question:** Where are the mistakes in the fake proof that $FinVect_k$ is not a closed category?

**Fake proof:** Wikipedia says that a category is closed if and only if it possesses an internal Hom functor. E.g. for a category $C$ which is a subcategory of $Set$, both $Hom(\cdot, B)$ and $Hom(A, \cdot)$ are functors whose target category is $C$ itself, rather than only just $Set$.

One can observe that the "relation" on $C \times C$ which takes a $k$-vector space $V$ to its dual $V^*$ is not a functor. But by definition $V^* = Hom(V, k)$, so that a contravariant Hom functor is what takes a vector space to its dual, and since the relationship between $V$ and $V^*$ is not functorial in $FinVect_k$, the contravariant Hom functor for $FinVect_k$ must only be a functor when considered as a map into $Set$. (I.e. one can not relate $V$ and $V^*$ canonically/functorially using linear maps -- we only have a canonical/functorial relationship between $V$ and its double dual.)

Since the contravariant Hom functor $Hom(\cdot, k)$, taking a vector space to its dual, is not a functor $FinVect_k \to FinVect_k$, the contravariant Hom functor in general can not be considered a functor into $FinVect_k$, so $FinVect_k$ has no internal Hom, so it is not a closed category.

Comment: On a general cartesian closed category $C$, the internal Hom operation is contravariant in the "exponent" argument: it is a functor $\mathscr{Hom} : C^{op} \times C \to C$.  So in particular $\mathscr{Hom}(\cdot, B)$ is a contravariant functor $C^{op} \to C$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler OHhh, so taking $V$ to its dual is really taking $V$ as an object in $FinVect_k^{op}$ to $V^*$ as an object in $FinVect_k$? And that wouldn't conflict with the Hom being internal, right? (If so, I am thinking of closing/deleting this question and asking a new question about how to consider $V$ as an object in $FinVect_k^{op}$, because that is probably the real source of my confusion.)

Comment: Well, the $C^{op}$ notation is just convenient shorthand for this requirement: if $X,Y,Z,W$ are objects of $C$, and you have $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_C(X,Y)$ and $g \in \operatorname{Hom}_C(Z,W)$, then you have an associated morphism in $\operatorname{Hom}_C(\mathscr{Hom}(Y,Z), \mathscr{Hom}(X,W))$ (which must also satisfy functoriality conditions).

Comment: Sorry, everywhere I said "cartesian closed category" substitute "closed monoidal category" - of course, $\mathbf{FinVect}_k$ isn't a cartesian closed category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your underlying error seems to be that you expect $\hom(\cdot, B)$ to be a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$, but that's wrong — it should be a functor $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{C}$.